# Android SDK installation failed

Tags: android, sdk, installation

I am new to android and i am trying to download android sdk in windows xp. I am behind a proxy

While installing sdk, I am getting this error

`Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml, reason: Connection to https://dl-ssl.google.com refused
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml, reason: Connection to https://dl-ssl.google.com refused`

On googling, i got the following 2 solutions for it.

1) Set proxy on Android SDK manager
2) Force http, instead of https.

Whar should I do to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

**SOLUTION**

We can set the proxy in the SDK manager. in 
Tools -> options.

There i set the proxy and port as shown in web browser (Internet Explorer/Firefiox)

its working. !

Comment: Could you fetch these files manually without any (network?) problem?

Comment: yes, I can see this xml in firefox

Comment: when I start the android sdk manager I can go to the tools menu and select options. there i can define an http proxy, but I can only force https instead of https

Comment: @axel. Thanks, its there. I missed it somehow. Thanks.

Comment: Dont keep any virus in ur pc sometime sdkmanager.exe gets off so better keep  this in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can set the proxy in the SDK manager. In Tools -> options.

There I set the proxy and port as shown in web browser (Internet Explorer/Firefiox)

Its working!

Comment: I'm having the same problem, what exactly do you mean by "set the proxy and port as shown in web browser"?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? If yes, there will be an ipaddress and port number for the proxy. Use that.

Answer (score 0):

Investigating this on my new Win 7 PC, I found my ADT pluggin to be missing. By adding this I solved the problem:
Downloading the ADT Plugin

Use the Update Manager feature of your Eclipse installation to install the latest revision of ADT on your development computer.

Assuming that you have a compatible version of the Eclipse IDE installed, as described in Preparing for Installation, above, follow these steps to download the ADT plugin and install it in your Eclipse environment.

```
Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software....
Click Add, in the top-right corner.
In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Click OK

Note: If you have trouble acquiring the plugin, try using "http" in the Location URL, instead of "https" (https is preferred for security reasons).
In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.

Note: If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.
```