# sdk manager not showing packages

Tags: android

i have installed android sdk from developers.android.com and a file is downloaded named as installer_r20.0.3-windows.exe. after i run this file android sdk installed. but when i run the sdk manager after it,it is not showing any packages. It is just showing the tools installed.

[image: the snapshot of the sdk manager is below]

i have searched on this site, many of us written solution is to set the proxy setting, but i am using a wireless home network in my laptop and don't have any proxy setting specified in my internet options..............

can anyone plzz help me with this .....i am just stuck at this point ....

plzzz do tell me what is the problem and how to solve it.

thanx in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Set the proxy settings under `SDK manager` -> `tools` -> `options` -> `port:8080`

Comment: The OP stated he *doesn't need to set a proxy* because he is on a home network.

Comment: sorry din pay attention to the details of the question

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your cache (Tools > Options, then click Clear Cache), then reload (Packages > Reload).

[image: Clear Cache button in right-center of dialog]

Comment: For some reason, you cannot access the place where the SDK files are published. Usually, that only happens in places where it is blocked by a firewall, whether that firewall is something on your PC (e.g., Windows Defender), on your network, or in your country.

Comment: i have disabled firewall also n tried but still no packages shown.

Comment: I am sorry, but at this point, I do not know what more to suggest.

Comment: I don't see Clear Cache option when I open SDK Manager > Tools > Options.

Comment: @AB1209: See the screenshot I added to the answer. "Clear Cache" is on the right side, roughly vertically centered.

Answer (score 0):

"We can set the proxy in the SDK manager. In Tools -> Options."

If you are behind proxy...
Set the proxy and port as shown in (Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Connections"

Useful links:

[Firewall:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819106/android-sdk-failed-to-fetch-url)

[Proxy and port:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613317/android-sdk-installation-failed)