# Android SDK Failed to fetch URL

Tags: android, sdk, windows-8

Android SDK failing fetch to the URL this is the SDK Manager log message.

```
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
Done loading packages.
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: Cannot assign requested address: connect
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml, reason: Bind Cannot assign requested address: connect
Done loading packages.
```

i am using `windows 8` 64 bit system.

Comment: Turn off windows firewall

Answer (score 8, accepted):

could be a problem due to your organisation's firewall..try setting proxy in Eclipse->Android SDK Manager->Tools->Options

Comment: thank you for response. actually it was my anti virus.

Comment: I found that clicking "force https" in Options fixed this for me. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @dylanlknowles Where is this "force https" setting?

Comment: Actually.  I found it.  I didn't realize there are proxy settings for the SDK manager separate from those I already specified in Eclipse.  Luckily, after specifying this proxy, I didn't even need to check "force https" to get it to work.