# Android SDK Install Packages Error

Tags: android, sdk, installation, package, proxy-server

I've been digging for hours over this, can someone please break it down in to basic newbie military grunt (what I am, currently deployed) terms cause I promise I'm not the only one that will benefit from it.

So you guys are saying to use a Proxy server under SDK-Tools and turn the Fetch option ON.

Well I'm using Chrome and only thing I found about a proxy is setting one up, requiring me to enter an IP address. I got mine from CMD-ipconfig. Got that and saw in the Chrome Settings of "setting up a proxy" with a spot for an IP Add and a Port said 80 even though it was grey out. I select to use Proxy, enter the IP Add from the CMD and using Port 80.

I go to my SDK Manager, Tools- HTTP- "My IP Add."; Port- 80 and Select Fetch.

I select the whole folder of Version 4.4, Google USB Drivers, Support Library and Android SDK Platform tools. I pretty much didn't touch anything other than Version 4.4 Folder. Click Install Packages.

It finished and only gave me two things out of the Version 4.4 Folder and Support Library. No Google USB Drivers.

If I leave that IP Add and Port in the Slots and uncheck the Fetch Option, I get:

> Preparing to install archives
>
> Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 19.0.1
>
> Download interrupted: Invalid argument: connect
>
> Downloading Documentation for Android SDK, API 19, revision 2
>
> Download interrupted: Invalid argument: connect
>
> Downloading SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 2
>
> Download interrupted: Invalid argument: connect
>
> Downloading Samples for SDK API 19, revision 3
>
> Download interrupted: Invalid argument: connect
>
> Downloading ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 19, revision 2
>
> Download interrupted: Invalid argument: connect
>
> Downloading Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 19, revision 2
>
> Download interrupted: Invalid argument: connect
>
> Downloading Google APIs (x86 System Image), Android API 19, revision 2
>
> Download interrupted: Invalid argument: connect
>
> Downloading Google APIs (ARM System Image), Android API 19, revision 3
>
> Download interrupted: Invalid argument: connect
>
> Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 19, revision 2
>
> Download interrupted: Invalid argument: connect
>
> Downloading Android Support Library, revision 19.0.1
>
> Download interrupted: Invalid argument: connect
>
> Downloading Google USB Driver, revision 9
>
> Download interrupted: Invalid argument: connect
>
> Done. Nothing was installed.

What is going on in there?

I am so eager to start working on the Android, but it has been nothing but issues, since I've downloaded the SDK bundle.

Please Help, I'm just a military guy who designs games in Unity and wants to try to put them on the Android.

Smarter people than me please lend me some words of your wisdom.

Comment: `So you guys are saying to use a Proxy server under SDK-Tools and turn the Fetch option ON.` Huh? Proxy servers have nothing to do with the Android SDK.  Where did you get this from?  Link?  If you don't use a proxy server in your browser, then you don't need one for the SDK.

Comment: This is one of the forums I was reading and trying to follow along:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613317/android-sdk-installation-failed

Comment: Got it.  You only need to setup a proxy if you are behind one.  if you are not behind one, or you do not know, try removing the proxy settings from the SDK manager.

Comment: @simon Ok so i turned off the proxy setting in Chrome>Settings>Proxy

Comment: @Simon And In the SDK Manager>Tools>Options> took the HTTP Proxy Server and Port off and turned off Forced HTTPS. When I try to Install my packages now i this error repeating for everything:                    Downloading Google USB Driver, revision 9
Download interrupted: Invalid argument: connect                        Ending with "Done.Nothing was installed."

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the solution for your exact case, but recent sdk manager versions may need admin rights to install packages.

1) Program Files (x86) > Android > android-studio > sdk >

2) right click on SDK Manager.exe and run as admin

3) try installing your packages now